# How to set UITableViewCell height depending on screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I download data from the web, it consists of text and image. I'm putting this data into UITableView, and I want image to be a background of UITableViewCell. 
All the images has the same resolution 620x350.

All the iPhones have different screen sizes so I need to scale image's width and height depending on screen size,and also do this to UITableViewCell.

What are the best solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: Why? The point of a bigger screen is to be able to show more info on the screen. From what you describe, why bother supporting the bigger screens if you are just going to show the same amount of info, just bigger?

Comment: I don't know how to resize image keeping the same aspect ratio. That is actually my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  CGFloat aspectRatio = 350.0f/620.0f;
   return aspectRatio * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;// assuming that the image will stretch across the width of the screen
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I understand you, this will give me the new height of the image depending on the screen size, right?

But I'm not sure where to put it, to set cell's height.

Comment: The tricky part are the constraints. This code is not enough. Then, in 1 line you have 3 errors: pointer for a primitive; int division for a float; no dot-comma at the end.

Comment: @Bennie , thank you. Your code is right. Though, I need to use constraints from Matteo Gobbi answer.

Comment: It is not really clear why ( @igrrik ) you choose this as correct answer if you are gonna use my approach.

Answer (score 3):

The BEST and clean solution, it is just **playing with the height of the cell**, letting the **image be resized automatically by Autolayout**.

It is easy:

1. In your cell, add an `UIImageView` and set the size you want to have when the cell has the actual height;
2. Set as constraints of this `UIImageView`, at least **top, bottom and one of the lateral border (right or left)**; set also the constraints to keep the **proportion width/height**;

At this point, when the cell **grow, the image grow in height**, and to keep the proportion (thanks constraint) it is **resized the width** as well, having **ALWAYS** the correct and proportioned size.

Now therefore, you have just to write the code for the cell's height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static CGFloat cellDefaultHeight = /*the default height of the cell*/;
    static CGFloat screenDefaultHeight = /*the default height of the screen i.e. 480 in iPhone 4*/;

    CGFloat factor = cellDefaultHeight/screenDefaultHeight

    return factor * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
}
```

Obviously, set the `contentMode` of the `UIImageView` to `AspectFill`.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer it seems to be the right one. But before I start to try it, only one question. 
What sizes should I use in storyboard by default?
My storyboard is the standard 600x600, I calculated the sizes of image for every screen and I have 
320x180 for 3.5/4 inch screen
375x211 for 4.7 inch
414x233 for 5.5 inch

Obviously the width is the maximum width of the screen, and height is calculated with the aspect ratio of 1.77.

Which of these I should use by default?

And also do I need to put UIImageView? Why not to use cell's background?

Comment: the height of the default cell for a screen of 320px width is something that you can decide. As also if put or not the image as background, but in that case you have problem of proportion when the screen is higher and the width is the same (ie iPhone 5). The image would be repeated.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It almost works, except of one issue. Look at the screenshots. In master-view the image is cut, and it happens an all devices.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/evuse7mqi3q7tsc/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202015-01-24%20%D0%B2%202.58.17.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0rssbq83dau4pd/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202015-01-24%20%D0%B2%202.58.38.png?dl=0

Comment: It depend from the image you set.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method in `HTTableViewDelegate` to return the height for each cell. In your case, you will want something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
}
```

Comment: So this will give the screen's resolution right? And then I have to make smh like switch-case statement, where I set cell's width and height?

Comment: it doesn't work properly without constraint for the image. Moreover this just return cells all with the height of the screen.

Comment: He didn't ask how to fit the image to the cell. He asked how to set the cell height to the screen height. Sizing the image to the cell size is the easy part.